# HIve select join with Rlike

Tags: left-join, hive

I have two tables on hive, one contains referer link that i extract from log.
the other one have regex to filter them.
I want to get only the referers that not match to regex.

my goal is:

```
SELECT iisrefer.referer 
FROM iisrefer
LEFT OUTER JOIN iisrefermap
ON iisrefer.referer rlike iisrefermap.referer
WHERE iisrefermap.referer IS NULL
```

as you can see [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-556) hive not support it, the first comment suggest a work around but i didnt understand how to execute it,

can someone help me please?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use smth like this:

> ```
> SELECT iisrefer.referer 
> FROM iisrefer
> LEFT OUTER JOIN iisrefermap
> ON (referer)
> WHERE iisrefer.referer rlike iisrefermap.referer
> ```

I wish it will help.